# Flask favicon not loading on Chrome even though the link exists

Tags: html, google-chrome, flask, favicon

I am trying to put a favicon on my Flask page. When I try it on IE, it works, but when I try it on Chrome (which is my usual browser), it does not load.
Yet if I go to static/favicon.ico, the image loads. Here is my HTML code:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico') }}">
```

I have tried clearing the cache but it didn't make a difference. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

To explore:

- **Cache issue**. Clearing the cache is sometimes not enough to get rid of the old favicon status. In other words, Chrome might remember that your icon was not working 5 minutes ago so it won't retry to load it, even while you fixed the icon a minute ago. Use the DevTools, Network tab, to make sure Chrome is loading your icon.
- **Errors in the console**. Although unlikely since it works with other browsers, there might be a problem with the image URL or something. It's a good practice to check the console.
- **Link in body**. WebKit is known to consider the `head` closed as soon as it encounters a `body`-only markup (eg. a `div`). And if the faulty markup is followed by `head`-only markups (eg. a `link`), these are ignored. To check this, use the DevTools to inspect elements and make sure you can find your favicon `link` markup. If it is not present whereas it is obviously in the HTML, you probably found the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I don't think it is a Cache issue because I tried it on my coworker's computer and it didn't work there either. He also was using Chrome. I tried it on both Firefox and IE and it worked though.
There are no errors in the console. I did check there. 
The link is also at the very top of my <head> tag, just under the Title, so I don't think it can be there. 

Are there some images that Chrome doesn't accept or something? I can't figure out what else it could be.

Comment: Is your site in production? If so, you can submit it to https://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_checker , it might give you a clue (disclaimer: I'm the author of this service).

Comment: same issue 2019, chrome, exact context

Comment: @toing_toing And did you find the solution?

Comment: @philippe_b see my answer

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. But if you go through the [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/favicon/), it clearly says to add this line to the head:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico') }}">
```

And then place the `favicon.ico` file in the static directory. Worked fine for me right away.

Comment: This is exactly the same as the OP